# Connect to another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Looking to connect to another domain in a PS script i have when a button is activated. I have tried a few things but have had little luck. I was looking to do this via `New-PSDrive` cmdlet but when i run my script even outside of the main script i am getting the below error:

New-PSDrive : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Server'.

Script bit i am using:

```
if (-not(Get-PSDrive DomainB)) {
    New-PSDrive `
        –Name DomainB `
        –PSProvider ActiveDirectory `
        –Server "DC.DomainB.local" `
        –Credential (Get-Credential ‘DOMAINB\Test’) `
        –Root ‘//RootDSE/’ `
        -Scope Global
    }Else{
    "Drive already exists"
    }
```

Not sure if this is no longer in use but i cannot seem to find an answer anywhere that's clear.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Why not leave off the `-Server` parameter when you create the drive? Then run `(Get-PSDrive DomainB).Server = 'DC.DomainB.local'`.

Comment: What actions do you want to perform via the psdrive?

Comment: I think there are better ways to do what you want to do, without using `New-PSDrive`. What do you want to do on that other domain?

Comment: The script is reading information from AD and reset password and unlock accounts.  So checking groups and folder perms.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser), [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword) and [`Unlock-ADAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/Unlock-ADAccount)?

Comment: So it is using Get-ADUser and -Unlock-Account. But they will connect to Domain A i need it to connect to Domain B to do some similiar tasks. So there fore i want the input to change to that domain via the button.

Comment: @AdminOfThings That i thought off but i get it doesn't find the PSProvider so it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a command which connects the Shell to Active Directory before adding the drive. The command only works when reading from Active Directory.